# Can i insert into two different tables from the same statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a car application, so cars have a bunch of information avaible to count
now i kept the essential on a table called `auto` and then i made a huge table for `attributes`
cool.
now i wish i can insert the same array data to two different tables under the same pdo

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO auto(year, make, model, mileage, price, vin, att1, att2,
    att3, att4, picture1, picture2, picture3, picture4, picture5, picture6, picture7, picture8, 
    picture9, picture10, picture11, picture12) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Can i do something like `'AND INSERT INTO attributes ('`

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $final = array_merge(array_values($vehicleinfo),array_values($paths));
        $sth->execute($final);
        echo '<h4 id="successMessage" style="color: red;">Vehicle added succesfully</h4>';
```

Comment: Short answer - you can't.

Comment: You should consider to outsource pictures into another table. This can lead to a hell of maintenance. I recommend to read about database normalization.

Comment: You can build a stored procedure to encapsulate the business logic you want and I think you can bind parameters in the same way when you call the stored procedure

Comment: @DanLee i could, but this fields only contain the filepath and not the actual picture, so its sort of appropiate, since its my essential table,, but now that you mentioned, can i relate the `auto_id` from one table to the other table with the same name auto_id?

Comment: @uillkk Yes, with foreign and primary keys you can do that. And no, it's not really appropriate, even with the file path :). You should consider reading some tutorials. Maybe this one here: [Database Normalization](http://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html)

Comment: You need to normalize your database.

Comment: You have the same data, but different tables. It's not difficult to create a function / class / whatever where you can pass data and table name as parameters and perform an insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be tempted to just loop over the tables you want to run the SQL on;

```
$tables = array('auto', 'attributes');

foreach($tables as $table) {

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' (year, make, model, mileage, price, vin, att1, att2, att3, att4, picture1, picture2, picture3, picture4, picture5, picture6, picture7, picture8, picture9, picture10, picture11, picture12) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $final = array_merge(array_values($vehicleinfo), array_values($paths));
    $sth->execute($final);

    echo '<h4 id="successMessage" style="color: red;">Vehicle added successfully to '.$table.'</h4>';

}
```

Or simply create a function so you can pass the required table into it;

```
insertVehicleInfo('auto');
insertVehicleInfo('attributes');

function insertVehicleInfo($table) {

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' (year, make, model, mileage, price, vin, att1, att2, att3, att4, picture1, picture2, picture3, picture4, picture5, picture6, picture7, picture8, picture9, picture10, picture11, picture12) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $final = array_merge(array_values($vehicleinfo), array_values($paths));
    $sth->execute($final);

    echo '<h4 id="successMessage" style="color: red;">Vehicle added successfully to '.$table.'</h4>';

}
```

Comment: what in the world is this

Comment: A solution to your problem.  You want to do the exact same thing to the same set of data, so either looping over the two tables you want to insert it into, or creating a function to pass the table name into, is the easiest way of doing what you want to achieve.

Comment: how would i make sure the attributes table gets the right auto_id from the other auto table which also has a primary key and auto incremt auto_id

Comment: You didn't mention that in your original question, however using the function, you could just return the auto_id, and pass it through to the second call to the function.  In the function you'd check if auto_id has been passed through, and if it has, use it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a trigger on insert into the first table to insert the same into the second one.

Comment: a trigger? should i just run a separated sql since it is kind of long either way, but im interested in understanding what you meant by trigger

Comment: @N.B. apparently triggers are kind of bad in this situation, they look hard to mantain, im thinking of managing sql the most i can in code instead of in the statement.. good to know triggers tho, thanks.

Comment: Yeah the problem with triggers or stored procedures, is that they're difficult to maintain over multiple databases / developer's development environments